# System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException: 'Operator '>' incompatible with operand types 'DateTime?' and 'Int32''

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, parsing, dbset

How can I correctly parse **sdate** ?

```
   IQueryable bddata = Junior2KepwareContext.Set(type)
       .Where($"C_NUMERICID == {idLinea}")
       .Where("C_TIMESTAMP > "+ startDate )
       .OrderBy("C_TIMESTAMP");
```

> System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException: 'Operator '>' incompatible with operand types 'DateTime?' and 'Int32''

[image]

### [image]

Comment: You already have a DateTime so why are you parsing.

Comment: @mjwills `idLinea ` is a byte

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but aren't you supposed to pass a callback to the where and orderby methods ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use parameters:

```
IQueryable bddata = Junior2KepwareContext.Set(type)
   .Where($"C_NUMERICID == {idLinea}")
   // @0 is first parameter in the list, @1 is second etc
   .Where("C_TIMESTAMP > @0", startDate) // startDate is of type DateTime, not string
   .OrderBy("C_TIMESTAMP");
```

It's a good practice to always use parameters instead of inlining values (so for example use it for `idLinea` too).

Comment: @MassimoVariolo well, because it was designed like this I guess. When you use parameters - parser knows their correct types (in this case it sees that `startDate` is `DateTime`) and is able to build correct query. If you don't use parameters - sometimes it can build correct query (if you use plain numbers for example) and sometimes it does not. So to avoid all the problems - just always use parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use only one string instead of several parameters, you are able to do so.

For your case it would give :

```
IQueryable bddata = Junior2KepwareContext.Set(type)
   .Where($"C_NUMERICID == {idLinea}")
   .Where($"C_TIMESTAMP > DateTime({startDate.Year},{startDate.Month},{startDate.Day}" )
   .OrderBy("C_TIMESTAMP");
```

Source : https://zzzcode.ai/answer-question?p1=Entity+Framework+Dynamic+LINQ&p2=use+dynamic+where+with+Datetime+with+only+one+string